# Global vs single file coverage thresholds when single file change in commit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I am using jest for testing my react components and using HUSKY for pre-commit checks.

I'm have a global threshold coverage with below config in jest.config.js

```
coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 90,
      statements: 90,
    },
  },
```

I'm having a use case where I'm using **npm run test -- --coverage --findRelatedTests** for checking test cases of only changed files with their coverage.

But the above command comparing the test cases of my changed file with global which results in below issue

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 5.74% ( 21/366 )
Branches     : 8.93% ( 10/112 )
Functions    : 1.33% ( 1/75 )
Lines        : 6.27% ( 21/335 )
================================================================================
coverage threshold for statements (90%) not met: 5.74%
coverage threshold for branches (80%) not met: 8.93%
coverage threshold for lines (90%) not met: 6.27%
coverage threshold for functions (80%) not met: 1.33%
```

What I want is that it should check and generate test coverage for only changed file, it should not include all the other files and then compare the coverage which will obviously be low.

Comment: maybe `--collectCoverageFrom` may help here. how does integration with Husky look like?

Comment: @skyboyer I already tries this but this does not seems to be working

Comment: have you found the way to pass changed files both to `--collectCoverageFrom` and `--findRelatedTests` with Husky ?

Comment: @skyboyer no thats what I am looking for,... jest documentation not clear regarding this.

Comment: let me rephrase: if you pass manually the same file(s) into `--collectCoverageFrom` and  `--findRelatedTests` does it calculate coverage properly? (I cannot check because `--findRelatedTests` does not work properly in my projects) if it works with manual passing then it's more about how to do that with Husky. if it does not work that way then it's bug in Jest's coverage calculation

Comment: @skyboyer, I passed files to --collectCoverageFrom manually but that did not work.

Answer (score -2):

for testing specific part of your code you need to add "only" key word to test case, see below:

```
describe(......, (): void => {
   it.only(..........
```

and then on command line run npm/yarn test src/...url to this documnet